# Can powercli tell me what the VM Name is when listing network adapters for vms?

Tags: powershell, powercli, vmware-server

I want to get a list of VMs with a given vlan name configured so that when I am rolling back a vlan, with ACI I am certain that it is gone.

This script works, I connect to the vcenter with powercli and pass in a vlan_name:

```
foreach ($vm in Get-VM){
  $nic = Get-NetworkAdapter -VM $vm.name
  if ( $nic.NetworkName -eq "{{ vlan_name }}" ){
    echo $vm.name
  }
}
```

The problem is, it is an O(n) sort of algorithm and takes a long time to run (I have thousands of VMs and hundreds of vlans)

The annoying thing is

`Get-VM | Get-NetworkAdapter`

lists all the vlan's quickly, but doesn't output the vm names.

Is there a way I can get the VM use by Network Adapter?

Comment: Just a guess as I can't test this locally, but does ```echo $nic.Parent.Name``` work instead of ```echo $vm.Name```? See https://developer.vmware.com/docs/powercli/latest/vmware.vimautomation.core/structures/vmware.vimautomation.vicore.types.v1.virtualdevice.networkadapter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This PowerShell lists out the VM name, the network adapter, and the type of network it's connected.

### PowerShell

```
Get-VM | Get-NetworkAdapter | Select-Object @{N="VM";E={$_.Parent.Name}}, Name, Type;
```

or

```
Get-VM | Get-NetworkAdapter | Select-Object Parent, Name, Type;
```

### Sample Output

```
VM                      Name                 Type
--                      ----                 ----
fserver3                Network adapter 1 Vmxnet3
pserver2                Network adapter 1 Vmxnet3
hserver2                Network adapter 1 Vmxnet3
lserver22               Network adapter 2 Vmxnet3
server1                 Network adapter 1 Vmxnet3
server2                 Network adapter 1 Vmxnet3
```

### PowerShell (Filter Network Name)

```
Get-VM | Get-NetworkAdapter | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "vlan_name"} | Select-Object @{N="VM";E={$_.Parent.Name}},Name,Type;
```

### Supporting Resources

- [Select-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/select-object.html)
- [Where-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/where-object.html)
- [Calculated_Properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.1#select-object)
- [Add a calculated property with Select-Object in PowerShell](https://4sysops.com/archives/add-a-calculated-property-with-select-object-in-powershell/)

Comment: thanks, I'm testing it out.  I realized when writing this question that all I really needed was evidence that the network name was in use.